# Proper use of const return values on a template class with specializers

Tags: c++, generic-programming

Here's a short template class example which I want my compiler to reject:

```
struct Vector {
  Vector(float a, float b, float c): x(a), y(b), z(c) {}
  float x, y, z;
};

template <typename T>
class Field {
public:
  const T doSomething() const;
};

template <typename T>
const T Field<T>::doSomething() const {
  T out(0);
  return out;
}

template <>
const Vector Field<Vector>::doSomething() const {
  return Vector(1,2,3);
}

template <>
const float Field<float>::doSomething() const {
  return 0.0f;
}

int main() {
  Field<float> g;
  Field<Vector> h;
  g.doSomething();

  // This should be illegal!
  h.doSomething() = Vector(3,4,5);
}
```

The compiler successfully throws an error! However, let's pretend I have to compile with `-Wall -Wextra`, for which this code generates the warning:

```
main.cpp:25:41: warning: type qualifiers ignored on function return type [-Wignored-qualifiers]
```

Ah, so you *could* remove the `const` qualifier on `doSomething()`'s return type, but that would pass my illegal line of code at the bottom. As a possible solution at least for my toy problem you can probably write the generic `doSomething()` to handle the primitive types and this warning is not generated, but say I have to specialize a primitive type. Is there a way to drop this warning short of altering the warning flags?

Comment: what are you talking about? that is illegal, since you want to assign something to a rvalue. BTW why would you ignore warnings?

Comment: `const` return values inhibit move semantics.  Is that really worth the "benefit" of making that line of code an error?

Comment: @BЈовић: You *can* assign to an rvalue of class type: `operator=` is a member function, and member functions can be called on rvalues.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Ah, right. So, the solution is to delete the move operator?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I'm at best a beginning C++ programmer, and I got into the habit of using const return values at the suggestion of Scott Meyer's Effective C++ book. I think the thinking is that (especially for operator overloads) someone could type `a * b = c`, which is probably an error, and we could check that statically if we make the return type constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With C++11, you can restrict the assignment operator to lvalue references like this:

```
struct Vector {
  Vector(float a, float b, float c): x(a), y(b), z(c) {}
  float x, y, z;
  Vector& operator=(const Vector&) & = default;
};
```

Now you can drop the const from the return type:

```
template <>
Vector Field<Vector>::doSomething() const {
  return Vector(1,2,3);
}
```

and your statement is still an error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘Vector’ and ‘Vector’)
   h.doSomething() = Vector(3,4,5);
```

Comment: Interesting answer, I may give it a go if I can use C++11, though I think it may be worth mentioning using g++ 4.7.3 I get a syntax error `main.cpp:4:38: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token`, however clang++ 3.2-1 seems to accept it.